# Getting error while trying to render array of object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {titlesCollection}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

I am getting this error while trying to render array of object, what I am doing wrong here?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-fontawesome';
const data = {
  otherTitles:[
        {
            titleHeading:"X",
            titles:["A","B","C","D"]
        },
        {
            titleHeading:"Y Z",
            titles:["E","F","G","H"]
        }        
    ]
}

export class OtherTitlesCollection extends React.Component{

  render() {
    const titlesCollection = data.otherTitles.map((othertitle)=>{
        let dataId = othertitle.titleHeading.replace(' ','');
        return(
            <div key={dataId}>
                <div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon name='plus-circle' data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target={"#"+dataId} role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls={dataId}/>
                    <label>{othertitle.titleHeading}</label>
                </div>
                <div  className="collapse" id ={dataId}>
                    {
                        othertitle.titles.map((title)=>{
                            return(<div key={title} style={{margin: "1px auto 1px 10px"}}>{title}</div>);
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    });
    return (
        {titlesCollection}
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because you try to render

```
return (
    {titlesCollection}
);
```

now since you did not wrap `titlesCollection` within a `div, span or Fragment`, it is assumed to be an object like

```
return (
     {titlesCollection: titlesCollection}
);
```

and hence you get an error, now that `titlesCollection` will be an array you can use `React.Fragment` like

```
return (
     <React.Fragment>
         {titlesCollection}
     </ React.Fragment>
);
```

or you can add a `div` around `titlesCollection` like

```
return (
     <div>{titlesCollection}</div>
);
```

or simply return `titlesCollection` like

```
return titlesCollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example

```js
import React from 'react';
const data = {
    otherTitles:[
        {
            titleHeading:"X",
            titles:["A","B","C","D"]
        },
        {
            titleHeading:"Y Z",
            titles:["E","F","G","H"]
        }
    ]
}

class TestJS extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        let sample = [];
        let sampleData = data.otherTitles;

        for (let i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i++) {
            sample.push(
                <div key={i}>{sampleData[i].titleHeading} - {sampleData[i].titles}</div>
            )
        }

        return(
            <div id="root">
                <p>Hello world</p>
                <div>{sample}</div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default TestJS;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-fontawesome';
const data = {
  otherTitles:[
        {
            titleHeading:"X",
            titles:["A","B","C","D"]
        },
        {
            titleHeading:"Y Z",
            titles:["E","F","G","H"]
        }        
    ]
}

export class OtherTitlesCollection extends React.Component{

  render() {
    return data.otherTitles.map((othertitle)=>{
        let dataId = othertitle.titleHeading.replace(' ','');
        return(
            <div key={dataId}>
                <div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon name='plus-circle' data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target={"#"+dataId} role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls={dataId}/>
                    <label>{othertitle.titleHeading}</label>
                </div>
                <div  className="collapse" id ={dataId}>
                    {
                        othertitle.titles.map((title)=>{
                            return(<div key={title} style={{margin: "1px auto 1px 10px"}}>{title}</div>);
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    });
   }
};
```

Please try upper code this will work for you and issue here is you try to return titlesCollection variable and it will not contain proper data when it was return so we will direct return looping data

Answer (score 0):

Just put `<div>` around `{titlesCollection}`.

```
return (
  <div>{titlesCollection}</div>
);
```